# Create dynamic SQL Select based on criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

How do I Select a certain column only if certain criteria is fulfilled?

I have a `#Pricelist_1 temp` table.
If `Price_list ='MY1'` it has `[Original Cost]` column, else this `[Original cost]` column is not existed.

How can I do dynamic SQL to select this `[Original cost]` only if `Price_list='MY1'`?

Tried using IIF but it doesn't work.

`IIF (a.Price_List='MY1',[Original Cost],'')`

SQL will throw an error that column `[Original Cost]` is not found when I run with `Price_list <> 'MY1'`

```sql
SELECT 
a.[Price_List],
a.[Price1],
a.[Price2],
a.[Price3],
IIF (a.Price_List='MY1',[Original Cost],'') --- If price_List='MY1' I want to select column [Original Cost] else I don't want to select this column.

INTO #A
FROM #Pricelist a (nolock)
LEFT JOIN #Premium p (nolock) ON a.[Product Group] = p.[Product Group] AND a.[Brand No] = p.[Brand No]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which SQL you are using, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server or else and version?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server 2014

Comment: Why don't you consider a simple case statement, you wont need dynamic sql for this

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a dynamic SQL. You can use a case statement. I think, you can take it from here.

```
SELECT 
a.[Price_List],
a.[Price1],
a.[Price2],
a.[Price3],
CASE WHEN a.price_List = 'MY1' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 [Original Cost] FROM #Pricelist WHERE.... (your filtering condition)) 
ELSE NULL END 

INTO #A
FROM #Pricelist a (nolock)
LEFT JOIN #Premium p (nolock) ON a.[Product Group] = p.[Product Group] AND a.[Brand No] = p.[Brand No]
```